# Batch IF DEFINED Not Working

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-7, command-prompt

I am trying to automatically delete certain folders from my user area using batch. I have chosen to filter any folders that should be deleted by using the `if defined` trick.

However, the following code is just removing all the folders.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b /ad`) do (
    set "true="
    if not "%%f"=="Custom Office Templates"     set true=1
    if not "%%f"=="Desktop"                     set true=1
    if not "%%f"=="Downloads"                   set true=1
    if not "%%f"=="Favourites"                  set true=1
    if not "%%f"=="Links"                       set true=1
    if not "%%f"=="My Documents"                set true=1
    if not "%%f"=="My Music"                    set true=1
    if not "%%f"=="My Pictures"                 set true=1
    if not "%%f"=="My Videos"                   set true=1
    if defined true (
        rd %%f
    )
)
```

Please help!

Comment: Please state what you mean by "not working". As written, your code will delete **every** directory. If it's doing that, then your code is "working".

Comment: Hm - true is set to "1" for EVERY directory...

Comment: Do you want to delete the listed direcories or all exept them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have implied with their comments - your logic is wrong.

Each of your IF statements can return FALSE for only one specific folder name. So if one of the IF statements is false, you can guarantee all the others will be TRUE. So if you think about, it is obvious that all folders will be deleted every time.

Also, you never undefined TRUE. So once it is set for one folder, it will remain set for all others.

If you only want to delete the listed folders, then:

```
for %%A in (
  "Custom Office Templates"
  "Desktop"                
  "Downloads"              
  "Favourites"             
  "Links"                  
  "My Documents"           
  "My Music"               
  "My Pictures"            
  "My Videos"              
) do rd %%A
```

If you want to delete all the existing folders ***except*** for the listed ones, then

```
for /d %%A in (*) do (
  set "exclude="
  for %%B in (
    "Custom Office Templates"
    "Desktop"                
    "Downloads"              
    "Favourites"             
    "Links"                  
    "My Documents"           
    "My Music"               
    "My Pictures"            
    "My Videos"              
  ) do if /i "%%A" equ "%%~B" set exclude=1
  if not defined exclude rd "%%A"
)
```

Note that the RD will fail if the folder is not empty. You can force it to succeed by deleting all content within the folder if you use

```
rd /s /q "%%A"
```